# What is the difference between ImageDataGenerator.flow() and ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 20, zoom_range = 15, width_shift_range=0.2, 
    height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.15, horizontal_flip=True, 
    vertical_flip=True, fill_mode='nearest')
```

What is the difference between `datagen.flow()` and `datagen.flow_from_directory`?

Comment: Hi ! In datagen.flow() , It takes data in the form of datasets like np.arrays directly where in case of datage.flow_from_directory it takes data from folders containing labelled images. But both return batches of augmented images in batches.Attaching relevant thread for reference. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow

Answer (score 1):

datagen.flow(): This method expects the input data to be provided as Numpy arrays. You would typically use this method when you have already loaded your entire dataset into memory as Numpy arrays. You pass the Numpy arrays of images and their corresponding labels to the flow() method to generate batches of augmented data.

datagen.flow_from_directory(): This method is designed to work with image data that is organized in a directory structure, where each subdirectory represents a class and contains the images belonging to that class. The method automatically infers the class labels from the directory structure. You only need to specify the directory containing the images, and the method will generate batches of augmented data with the appropriate labels.